# savepoint is not recognized in db2

Tags: db2, savepoints

I have following query -

```
SAVEPOINT A ON ROLLBACK RETAIN CURSORS;

select max(id) from testdb.table1;

ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT A;

commit
```

I am getting following error

```
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT A
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0880N  SAVEPOINT "A" does not exist or is invalid in this context.  
SQLSTATE=3B001
```

I am new to DB2, I didnt get any start transaction type statement, however commit is present.

How to resolve this error?

**Resolution**

I got following -

```
update command options using c OFF; 

SAVEPOINT A ON ROLLBACK RETAIN CURSORS;

select max(id) from testdb.table1;

ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT A;

commit;

update command options using c ON ;
```

It is working fine in my context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update command options using c OFF; 

SAVEPOINT A ON ROLLBACK RETAIN CURSORS;

select max(id) from testdb.table1;

ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT A;

commit;

update command options using c ON ;
```